# Fixed page layout HTML

Tags: html, css, fixed-width, page-layout

I am really new to web design, so please help me out! I am trying to get a fixed page layout for my personal website http://oatmeeel.com/. I used fixed width in `px` and `html {min-width: 1440px}`. This works fine in MAMP localhost (image 1). The page is scrollable and the width is the same.

But when I upload the file on the server, the page does not have fixed dimensions and the width adjusts relative to the width of the window (image 2).

Any idea on why it works on MAMP but not on the server? I am using Cyberduck to upload to hostgator. Thank you in advance!

[image: image_1]
[image: image_2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was checking it in chrome and it works fine for me.. But try add to header

```
   header{ 
     float: left;
   }
```